# Spring remember-me with MongoDB does not delete tokens

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-security, remember-me

I followed [this](http://dimafeng.com/2015/06/22/remember-me/) tutorial to implement remember-me functionality with MongoDB.

The tokens are saved in the database when i click the rememberme checkbox in the login page. If i delete the db entry manually and the cookie JSESSIONID maxage has expired i am getting logged out and if the JSESSIONID has expired and the remember-me cookie does not, i am still logged in which is great.

All works well but i have a question. The removeUserTokens function is never called, should i manually delete the token entry from the database? If yes where should i implement this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching it a bit more i found that when i logout and having this to my configuration:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/signup", "/about").permitAll().antMatchers("/doctor/**")
            .hasRole("DOCTOR").anyRequest().authenticated().and().rememberMe().rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
            .tokenRepository(tokenRepository).tokenValiditySeconds(1209600).and().formLogin().loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error=true").permitAll().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").permitAll();....
```

the removeUserTokens method is called and the associated token is deleted from the db. I think the trick is made by:

```
.logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").invalidateHttpSession(true)
```

Also as notionquest said above i added a Spring cron job to run every Friday at 3 AM in case of something is left in the db.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 3 * * FRI")
public void doScheduledWork() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, -2);

    tokenRepository.deleteBeforeDated(calendar.getTime());
    logger.info("INFO", "Cron job runed at " + new Date() + " until " + calendar.getTime() + " !");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It has to be deleted manually (e.g. by batch process) per  [Java doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/rememberme/PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices.html).

**PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices**

> Note that while this class will use the date a token was created to
>   check whether a presented cookie is older than the configured
>   tokenValiditySeconds property and deny authentication in this case, it
>   will not delete these tokens from storage. A suitable batch process
>   should be run periodically to remove expired tokens from the database.

The abstraction (PersistentTokenRepository) used by PersistentTokenBasedRememberMeServices to store the persistent login tokens for a user.